# Get folder and files Google Drive API with Shared Device and Service Account

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm working with a Google Service Account, I have access to Google Drive API and a Shared Unit.

I need to get access to all the files and folders from a Shared Unit.
I tried a lot of different ways to do this.

```py
drive_service.files().list(
    q = f"'{parent_folder}' in parents",
    spaces = 'drive',
    supportsTeamDrives=True
).execute()

>> {'kind': 'drive#fileList', 'incompleteSearch': False, 'files': []}
```

```py
drive_service.files().list(
    q = f" parents in '{parent_folder}'",
    spaces = 'drive',
    supportsTeamDrives=True
).execute()

>> {'kind': 'drive#fileList', 'incompleteSearch': False, 'files': []}
```

```py
drive_service.files().list(
    spaces = 'drive',
    supportsTeamDrives=True
).execute()

>> {'kind': 'drive#fileList', 'incompleteSearch': False, 'files': []}
```

```py
drive_service.drives().list().execute()

>> {'kind': 'drive#driveList',
 'drives': [{'kind': 'drive#drive',
   'id': '0AOELwkzr21lFUk9VA',
   'name': 'foo'}]}
```

I know a have access because I can upload files to the parent folder.
Also, there are files in the parent folder.

Do you have any clue?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out.

An additional parameter had to be passed:

```py
includeItemsFromAllDrives = True,
supportsAllDrives = True
```

This works:

```py
drive_service.files().list(
    q = f"'{parent_folder}' in parents",
    spaces = 'drive',
    includeItemsFromAllDrives = True,
    supportsAllDrives = True
).execute()
```

Comment: I have been trying to use ChatGPT to help advise on APIs.  Sometimes it is OK but often does not get the nuances.  I have been trying to use the Java Google Drive API with OAuth2 and service account. I could not get shared drive contents to list.  This answer solved the problem.  In Java, the `setIncludeItemsFromAllDrives` and `setSupportsAllDrives` methods are used and only the second one seems to be supported depending on how the API is used.  By doing this, the credentials scope can be `DRIVE_READONLY`, share the drive with the service account email, and no need for domain-wide delegation.